# In Anylogic how do you extract the name of an object so i can use and assign it as a Text value? (Object >> Text)

Tags: tostring, text-extraction, anylogic

The Problem: An agent has a parameter that refers to an object (lets say an INode). I want to get and use the name of that INode as plain text without writing a function that maps INodes to their names. If currentLocation (which has a value of Node12) is the parameter, in a snippet, it looks like:

agent.currentLocation

Is there a name property of Parameters or other Objects that i can reference and it returns a String (just the text "Node12" in this case)? I have tried all kinds of references with parameter.name, getValue, etc, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `INodes` you can use `myNode.getName()`, as you can for every object in Java.

However, you cannot get the name of parameters, variables, etc. And you shouldn't do that, it is considered bad practice :-)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin.